# what is portable executable format and why we need it?

Tags: linker, exe

what are executable formats and what is the use of them?
ex-PE format,com format,ms dos format
why they are necessary and what information does they contain?

Comment: A full *discussion* about what all those formats contain and why they are (or was) needed is far too broad a topic for a Q&A site. Can you narrow down the question? For instance, what sparked this question? Do you have a specific question about one of the formats? If you're on a "I'm going to broaden my knowledge about stuff" type of quest then Google is probably a far better source for information on this topic.

Comment: just want to know the work of these?

Comment: Yeah, but these are *big* topics. There's tons of information in these file formats and they serve *many* purposes, such as providing information *about* the executable, *for* the operating system, *for* debuggers, *for* jitters (depending on format), relocation tables, etc. As I said, these are far too broad for a Q&A site and there is no "just" about it at all. **You really have to narrow the question down**

Comment: A glib answer would be that they are necessary to allow for the operating system to load and understand the contents of the executable. The reason there are different formats is because of different operating system and different people with different needs.

Comment: is compiler make these structures or loader?

Answer (score 1):

PE (Portable Executable) is the file format for .exe, .dll, .sys, etc...

The PE files contain the code(program) and additional information(eg.: import and exports tables, .dlls ,resource management) wrapped inside it. 
Program Loader interprets the information and map the file to the memory and load shared libraries that are need.